# Continuous footnote numbering

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I would like footnote numbering to continue over pages and chapters. In my document it's reset every chapter. I'm using the report documentclass.

Comment: Same for `book` class...

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use `\counterwithout`.

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.\footnote{The first footnote.}

\chapter{bar}

Some text.\footnote{The second footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image: continuous numbering independent of chapter]

Comment: In a current LaTeX (not older than 2018-04-01), `\counterwithout` is part of the kernel, so the `\usepackage{chngcntr}` is not needed any more. See https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf

Comment: This did not work in my case... I am using University of Chicago's ETD document class from here: https://github.com/mvzink/ucetd-latex

Comment: If you use `\counterwithout` with current LaTeX, avoid loading `chngcntr` package, because it messes up numbers of references to figures.

Answer (score 0):

`\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}` provides a separate sequence of footnote numbers in each chapter, apparently only if the chapter does not contain sections, which each have a different sequence of footnotes, using letters instead of numbers, without being commanded to do so.

Comment: This isn't what `\counterwithout` does and, if it was, this wouldn't answer the question, while, if it doesn't, it's just duplicating the existing answer.