# Continuous table numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices

I am listing a bunch of pages in an Appendix.  If I do the appendix as `\appendixpage`, after a chapter 1 (for testing), I get all tables numbered 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.436.  (Yes, I have 436 tables, and it's only warming up.)

How can I place all of the tables in the appendix so that they are numbered A.1, A.2, ..., A.436?  Alternatively, how do I make sure all of the tables in the whole memoir document are numbered continuously, 1, ..., 523 (I have more tables before the Appendix)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make tables numbered A.1, A.2 etc. in the appendix, use the `\appendix` command:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{table}
bla
\caption{First table}
\end{table}

\appendix

\chapter{bar}

\begin{table}
bla
\caption{Second table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For continous table numbering, the answer is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering/10449#10449). That is, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

Comment: `memoir` incorporates `chngcntr` into the class, so for `memoir` (which Alexy is using) you don't need the `\usepackage` command.  But the general question is better answered without reference to `memoir` anyway.

Comment: @Alan: I take it that `\appendixpage` is a memoir-specific command, then?

Comment: Yes, it creates an unnumbered part-like page with the appendix name (and adds it to the toc).

Comment: @Alan: Thanks for the info! @Alexy: `\appendixname` does what Alan says, but it doesn't start the appendix by itself -- for this, you have to use `\appendix`.

Comment: @Alexy If you want your tables in the main text numbered sequentially (independent of chapter) you can use the `\counterwithout` command; if you *also* want  your tables in the Appendix to be numbered A1, A2 ... you can add `\counterwithin{table}{chapter}` right after the `\appendix` command to do this.

Answer (score 5):

To number the floats sequentially, as seen from the code in memoir, you have to redefine internal commands within the memoir class:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
}

\renewcommand\@memback@floats{%
  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
}
\makeatother
```

Seems to work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other newcomers to LaTeX, the

```
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

command needs to follow

```
\begin{document}
```

because it won't have any effect in the preamble.

Comment: Although it is true that typesetting of tables are only possible *after* `\begin{document}`, counter settings may be included in the document preamble *or* the document itself. So, you can put `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` anywhere; it will take effect from that point onward.

Comment: Yes, I thought that is how it should work; however, empirically, with my setup, in the preamble there was no effect, while in the document, there was. I'm more inclined to go with what works in practice than what should work in theory but requires a deeper understanding of internals than I currently have.