# Numbering figures and tables by their section

Tags: floats, numbering

I am having trouble formatting my list of figures and list of tables.

Currently, my tex document is printing the list in the following manner:

> 1 Foreign Key Constraint Problem Due
>   to Improper Table Design. . . . 3
>
> 2 Application Flow of Territory
>   Maintenance Tool. . . . . . . . . . .
>   . . 4

But I want to number figures by their sections:

> 3.1.2 Foreign Key Constraint Problem Due to Improper Table Design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is the counterpart of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering) one. So: use the [chngcntr](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/chngcntr.html) package.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome, your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: If you use `\counterwithout` with current LaTeX you don't need `chngcntr` package anymore, moreover you should avoid loading it because it messes up numbers of references to figures.