# Change caption name of figures

Tags: floats, formatting, captions, naming

How can I modify the caption name of a figure? For example I have

```
\caption{This is a figure.}
```

and by default the caption appears as

> Figure 1: This is a figure.

However I want

> Fig.1 - This is a figure.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

First, you have to redefine `\figurename`.

Option1: Without using the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
```

Option2: With `babel` (and English as language):

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
```

For other `babel` languages you need to use the proper `\captions<language>` command instead of `\captionsenglish` in the command above.

For changing the separator between label and caption text, I recommend the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** In case anyone wonders how to change the caption name of tables: Redefine `\tablename`.

Comment: Ok, but the figure is numbered like Fig. 0.0.1.. how can i remove that numerotation?

Comment: @qwerty: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17127/510) question for general hints about changing the numbering of figures and tables.

Comment: Ok, and if i don't want Latex to automatically number my figures, what can i do? I do not want any numbers

Comment: You could simply add some "caption-like" text to your `figure` environment.

Comment: \includegraphics[height=59mm]{histogram.jpg}
\caption{My caption.}    Well, my figure is still numerotated..

Comment: Replace `\caption{My caption}` with `\par\smallskip My caption`.

Comment: remove all numbers: `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{}`

Comment: or you can use `\caption*{}`

Comment: Using the `figurename=` key for the `caption` package (as in `\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}`
) you can change the figure name and this will work whether `babel` is used or not.

Comment: double chocolate for you sire! ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for me; the command \figurename is not defined.

Comment: using xelatex, to remove the caption prefix altogether, this answer does the trick: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40182/68905

Comment: Is there a way to rename some figures? That is, some of my figures should really be called "formulas"

Comment: This produces labels such as Fig.1 below the images. But what about the references. \cref{fig1:fig3} Produce Figure 1c. How can I get Fig.1c or something like that.

Comment: What should I write instead of endash to make it a  dot like Fig. 1.?

Comment: This approach works "like a charm" also with `\captionsspanish` :)

Comment: Is there anything like `\algorithmname` for algorithms?

Answer (score 62):

This is a simple solution:

```
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
```

Works with and without `babel`. Use `tablename` for tables.

Comment: Note that it has to be placed after `\usepackage{babel}` or `babel` will redefine the names back to its default settings.

Comment: @VáclavPavlík I believe not if you write the above solution after the import.

Comment: but if I subfigures it produces an error: "Package caption error: can be used only in preamble...

Comment: Hello! But for rename only one and not all?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the file `pseudocode.sty` (if you are using a `pseudocode` environment) and changing the word "algorithm" by "algorithme".

The file is installed C:/programfile/...Miktex...pseudocode

Comment: pardon: file "pseudocode.sty"  not "pseudocode.sys"

Comment: It is bad practice to change the files originally included in your TeX distribution.

Comment: You better edit your answer than correcting it in a comment!

Comment: Despite the fact, that it is bad advice to change distributed files, this is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: This is a bad solution. You should use existing functionality or extent it with a package (such as `caption`).