# How to remove figure label?

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow

I'm using `floatrow` package to organise my figures, but then would like to add an image in the preliminary chapters which should NOT contain figure label e.g. *Figure 1*, but only the caption *To my family*. I also want to eliminate the underline of caption which `floatrow` does. Is there a way to get around this? The code is as below:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\color{blue}\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=6cm]{./Figures/flower.png}}
{\caption{To my family}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: text can be included directly in a figure; it's not necessary to use a caption.  try `\centerline{...}` with perhaps some `\vspace` above it.

Comment: @ barbara: Thanks! It works `\centerline{\includegraphics[width=6.0cm, height=6.0cm]{./Figures/flower.png}}`                                               
 `\hspace{8\baselineskip}To my extended family`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use `\caption*` command instead of `\caption` provided by [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{Your picture is here.}
{\caption*{To my family}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @BrettHarry: If this answered your question please mark it so using the tick symbol at the left side. This concludes the question and assigns points to the answerer and to you.

Comment: This breaks `\label`, as it seems to no longer know the figure number

Comment: With `\caption*`, the caption text is no longer justified. It is simply centred.

Answer (score 39):

Since you are using the `caption` package, you could also set the option `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}`

or to change the options at a specific point use `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`.
Taken from [Caption manual](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf)