# Table caption without the word "table"

Tags: tables, captions

Whenever I put

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{My great table}
\end{table}
```

It would end up with the name "Table 1: My great table". I don't want the prefix "Table 1:". Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: Possible related question: [How to remove figure label?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21795/2580)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I recommend you to use the `\caption*` command from the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2
\end{tabular}
\caption*{My great table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As @egreg suggests there's also the possibility to do it using the `\captionsetup` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2
\end{tabular}
\caption{My great table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Doing so you don't always need to use `*`.

The solution you're using depends on what you're trying to achieve. The second one adds your table to the list of tables whereas `\caption*` does not. (Thanks @Herbert)

Comment: You could also point out the possibility of setting `labelformat=empty`, that avoids the having to add *.

Comment: `\caption*` and `labelformat=empty` are quite different in their behaviour! The latter will be in the table of contents and the first not

Comment: Sorry for the necro, but when I tried to do this, LaTeX inserted a space between the caption and the table. Packages are `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, `booktabs`, `multirow`. Table looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/RobRoseKnows/506fb5bd19417803e6e1d2935b7de97c).

Comment: I'll have to second that. Same happened to my document. It's not hugely important for the thing I'm doing atm, but it *does* add a space, which might be unwanted in other cases. @egreg any ideas?

Comment: @thymaro I see no space. In order to verify it, I added `<blank line>\centerline{My great table}` before the `\caption`. The two text appear equally centered. Please, ask a new question with all details for reproducing the issue.

Comment: @egreg ok, will do that in the afternoon

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested to include it in either table of contents or list of tables, then simply add the title inside table environment as a normal text without using caption command

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    Title above (as usual)
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        1 & 2
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    Title below
\end{table}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then, even the text of the caption would not appear in the table of contents.

Comment: Yes It will not appear in either table of contents or list of tables