# How to remove table name from caption in beamer?

Tags: beamer, captions

Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names,table}]{beamer}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303060/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303091/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303021/13173

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% otherwise fourier's font configuration will be partially overridden
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
   \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
   \makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}%
   \hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt%
   \hspace{\labelsep}%
}

\newlength{\CVbreakdotsep}% length to change spacing between dots
\setlength{\CVbreakdotsep}{0.6mm}

\newcommand{\CVbreakdot}{% command for smaller dots
   \scalebox{0.6}{\textbullet}%
}

\newcommand{\CVbreak}{% command for the break itself
   \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \hspace*{8.715mm}% <--- align dots with vertical line
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
         \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
         \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
         \CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot
         \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
      }%
   } \\%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
   \caption{Timeline, really?}\vskip -1.5ex
   \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
   \begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
      \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.5ex]
      1969 & Lassa virus. \\
      \CVbreak
      1989 & Guanarito virus, Venezuela. \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Nunkulla's Test Code

Have the following line before `\caption{...}`

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
```

I run Nunkulla's code in my system of OS X 10.11.4 with MacTeX 2015 and I see no such an effect as Nunkulla sees, and I did have `\captionsetup{...}` active in one instance

[image]

**Solution**: Run `TeX Live Utility` and update packages. The [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/21/) and ... were issued after the release of MacTeX 2015 so are not included in the package. The same output as in the accepted answer now.

---

How can you have no *Table* in Beamer's Cut?

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{caption}`
`\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41880/table-caption-without-the-word-table

Comment: @Nunkulla Does not work with `\usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`.

Comment: It works for me. Did you insert those commands after `\usepackage{array, booktabs}`?

Comment: @Nunkulla Yes. Please, provide it as an answer because I cannot get it work in OS X. Please, provide also a picture as an evidence.

Comment: Could be related to https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/21/. If yes, updating should solve the issue.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Yes, it is related because the patch was released after MacTeX 2015 release. The default installation of MacTeX 2015 does not include the patch and also does not involve automatic run of `TeX Live Utility` for updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer follows @egreg's suggestion in the answer posted here: [Table caption without the word "table"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41880/table-caption-without-the-word-table), using the `caption` package and the `captionsetup` option from that package. The correct usage of caption setup in this instance is given in section 3.2 of the `caption` package manual.  Since the desired result is to suppress the label in a specific table environment, the command `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}` must be placed in the environment where the label would otherwise be generated.

This is demonstrated in the following code where in the first vertical timeline, "Table" is suppressed using `captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`. In the subsequent example, which duplicates the caption and table from the first example, but this time suppressing `captionsetup{labelformat=empty}` command, produces the label "Table".

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names,table}]{beamer}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303060/13173
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303091/13173
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/13173
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303021/13173

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% otherwise fourier's font configuration will be partially overridden
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}


\newcommand{\foo}{%
   \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
   \makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}%
   \hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt%
   \hspace{\labelsep}%
}

\newlength{\CVbreakdotsep}% length to change spacing between dots
\setlength{\CVbreakdotsep}{0.6mm}

\newcommand{\CVbreakdot}{% command for smaller dots
   \scalebox{0.6}{\textbullet}%
}

\newcommand{\CVbreak}{% command for the break itself
   \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \hspace*{8.715mm}% <--- align dots with vertical line
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
         \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
         \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
         \CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot
         \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
      }%
   } \\%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}   % suppress label ``Table''
   \caption{Timeline, really?}\vskip -1.5ex
   \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
   \begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
      \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.5ex]
      1969 & Lassa virus. \\
      \CVbreak
      1989 & Guanarito virus, Venezuela. \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
%   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} % Label ``Table'' is not suppressed
    \caption{Timeline, really?}\vskip -1.5ex
    \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
        \toprule
        \addlinespace[1.5ex]
        1969 & Lassa virus. \\
        \CVbreak
        1989 & Guanarito virus, Venezuela. \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean with `captions` package probably `caption` package. Right?

Comment: I reproduced your code in my system. I do not get the same output as you but *Table* in both tables. What is your system? I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Masi You have to uncomment the `\captionsetup` line

Comment: @Masi Regardless of whether I compile this with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I get the same output I posted. The only thing I can think of is to check for package updates.

Comment: @egreg I did uncomment it.

Comment: To remove the labels from all tables one can use `\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}`. There might also be the possibility to do this without the `caption` package by use of Beamer's `caption name` template (but I didn't look into it and there is no obvious way to limit it to just tables).

Answer (score 2):

Don't want a caption? Don't use a caption!

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names,table}]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% otherwise fourier's font configuration will be partially overridden
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
    \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
    \makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}%
    \hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt%
    \hspace{\labelsep}%
}

\newlength{\CVbreakdotsep}% length to change spacing between dots
\setlength{\CVbreakdotsep}{0.6mm}

\newcommand{\CVbreakdot}{% command for smaller dots
    \scalebox{0.6}{\textbullet}%
}

\newcommand{\CVbreak}{% command for the break itself
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
        \hspace*{8.715mm}% <--- align dots with vertical line
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
            \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
            \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
            \CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot
            \hspace{2mm}% <--- extra vertical space
        }%
    } \\%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{table}
            \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
            Timeline, really?\linebreak
            \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
            \begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
                \toprule
                \addlinespace[1.5ex]
                1969 & Lassa virus. \\
                \CVbreak
                1989 & Guanarito virus, Venezuela. \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Masi Depends on what you want for your other captions. For this example, only the `booktabs` package is necessary, all the other packages are only there, because they had been in your (non-)minimal example.

Comment: I got a comment here that it is `\\\` is corresponding to `\par` here so not correct. So I think there is a need to use a caption here but without *Table*. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303087/13173

Comment: @Masi I admit, that `\\` is bad style to force a linebreak, but this has nothing to do  whether or not you need a caption. And your linked commend does not imply this at all! I am missing some context to really understand the comment of @crf, it sounds like you tried to modify the code in a way that does not correspond to the question you asked there.