# How to remove the colon in the caption of `algorithm2e`

Tags: beamer, formatting, captions, algorithm2e

I am preparing a presentation, and I want the title of the algorithm without any numbering, and without any colons.

I use the commands

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}
```

but now the colon still remains.

How can I get rid of the colon before the title of the algorithm?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,noend]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}
\usecolortheme{frigatebird}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pseudocode template}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption[labelformat=empty]{\sc{TitleOfTheAlgorithm}}
    \KwIn{What is given to the algorithm}
    \KwOut{What the algorithm gives back}
    the commands\;
    executed\;
    by\;
    the algorithm\;

\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303239/108724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `algorithm2e`-fashion solution :

1. Use `\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}` to remove the ":" in the algorithm caption see §9.2.2 of algorithm2e documentation
2. Use `\SetAlCapNameFnt{\scshape}` to change the caption text font with small caps see §9.5.4 of `algorithm2e` documentation

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,noend]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{}
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}
\usecolortheme{frigatebird}

% Removes the ":" in algorithm caption see §9.2.2 of algorithm2e documentation
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{}
% Styles the caption text with small caps see §9.5.4 of algorithm2e documentation
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\scshape}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pseudocode template}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{TitleOfTheAlgorithm}
    \KwIn{What is given to the algorithm}
    \KwOut{What the algorithm gives back}
    the commands\;
    executed\;
    by\;
    the algorithm\;

\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better answer coming along the lines of `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`, but I don't know what circumstances that applies to. Here is a dirty answer

```
\makeatletter \def\algocf@capseparator{}\makeatother
\renewcommand\AlCapNameSty[1]{\unskip\strut\textnormal {#1}\unskip}
```

The first line eliminates the `:` separator. The second line eliminates the space that normally comes after `:`. I've also inserted `\strut` because layout with rules was too ugly.