# Subfigure Labeling Latex

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I have a quick question about labeling subfigures: I am putting in figures side-by-side using the `subfigure` package, but I don't want the labelling to be included in the caption (i.e (a), (b), (c), etc). How do I go about doing this?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\hfill

\subfigure[caption 1]

{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\textwidth]{fig1.png}}

\hfill

\subfigure[caption 2]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\textwidth]{fig2.png}}

\hfill

\caption{Title for both}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please update your question to include a full, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). For example, do you also use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? Ideally, your MWE should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I did not try this but [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/how-to-remove-figure-label) it says that you can use `\caption*` command instead of `\caption` provided by the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

Or to change the options at a specific point use `\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}`. See the [caption manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.