# Abbreviate "figure"

Tags: floats, captions, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

I'm using scrbook for the document class. Is there an easy way to abbreviate "Figure 1" in order to have "Fig. 1" ? The proposed answer didn't solve it, see a MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,toc=bibliographynumbered,toc=flat]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\textbf{\label{fig:Verlaufsformen-der-MS}Verlaufsformen der MS als graphische Abbildung nach Lublin und Reingold 1996}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `babel`, use `\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}}`. See my answer in the question linked above as "Possible Duplicate".

Comment: Gorgeous, I didn't get the "captionsngerman"-thing, but now it works. Can I accept this as the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Jan: I think so, since voting on closed questions are still possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KOMA-Script classes have a macro called `\figurename` which stores, you guessed it, the name of `figure` floats. If English is the language in force, this macro's value is, by default, "Figure". Use the command

```
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
```

to reset this macro to contain "Fig.".

Comment: This also holds for the regular document classes. Search for `\figurename` in [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) (say). The second entry declares `\figurename`, used by `\fnum@figure`.

Comment: This might not work if the OP uses `babel`, as explained in my answer to the question linked above as "possible duplicate of".