# Change abstractname

Tags: naming, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)
>   [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr)

I'm using the `book` class in my document and I created an abstract using this piece of code:

```
\newenvironment{abstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfill\begin{center}%
    \bfseries\abstractname\end{center}
    {\vfill\null}
```

Now I would like to change `\abstractname`. I tried `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Name}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: "It didn't worked" isn't very informative, but a) The book class doesn't define `\abstractname`, so you'll have to do it using `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand` b) if you did that already, the problem might be your use of the `babel` package; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures

Comment: Vote to reopen, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/same-disease-different-symptoms

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82993/how-to-change-the-name-of-document-elements-like-figure-contents-bibliogr