# How to make figure caption boldface

Tags: fonts, captions, bold

When I create a figure caption, LaTeX automatically creates the `Figure1:` part and then the caption. How to make the `Figure1` part boldface? My figure TeX codes is this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=80mm]{images/tftype.png}|\includegraphics[width=80mm]{images/tftype1.png}
\caption{An overview of structural variants of transcription factors. Each specific variant binds to a certain class of DNA motifs (shown in blue).  Some of the motifs have a high affinity for the TATAAA box were others favor specific sequences somewhere in the promoter region. {\small http://www.nature.com/scitable/resource?action=showFullImageForTopic\&imgSrc=37950/sadava\_14\_15\_FULL.gif}}
\end{figure}
```

I'm a beginning TeX user and some things are still strange to me. Any help is appreciated.

My desired output is : **Figure1:** some very interesting information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change caption name of figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

Comment: @m0nhawk No, it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @m0nhawk indeed its a very similar question but couldnt find it by searching. I now fixed it but how to change the number

Comment: @egreg: It looks very similar to me.

Comment: @m0nhawk That's only for changing the label name, not the formatting of "label+number"

Comment: @m0nhawk are we going to discuss if its a duplicate or do we all want to have as many help as possible on the web!

Comment: I agreed that I was too fast to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package; the `labelfont` key allows you to specify `bf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{test figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is to apply to all floats (not just `figure`), instead of

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
```

load the package in the following way:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```