# How to change figure caption to Fig. 1. in stead of Fig. 1:

Tags: floats, ieeetran

My Figure caption is now like this: (Fig. 1:Caption of figure) and I want to change it to (Fig. 1. Caption of figure).

Also in the Table caption I want to get it like this: (Table II. Title of table).
I am uisng IEEE conference document.

Comment: I think this question and the associated answers can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17489/31058.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your setup since the `IEEEconf` document class -- which you say you're using -- already uses a dot (`.`) rather than a colon (`:`) to separate the float's number from the caption text. Are you maybe loading some specialized packages to modify the appearance of floats? Alternatively, are you maybe using an obsolete version of the file IEEEconf.cls? The version of the file available on the CTAN (and distributed with current versions of TeXLive and MikTeX) is `v1.4, 2009/04/05`.

Other than the separator issue, I discern two additional objectives you're looking to achieve: Typeset `Fig.` rather than `Figure` as the "name" of `figure` floats, and use Roman instead of arabic numbering for `table` floats. Both of these elements are easy to implement via `\renewcommand` instructions. (Note that the font used for the figure and table captions is **Helvetica-Bold** as per the default settings of the `IEEEconf` document class.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEconf}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
Hello
\caption{Caption of figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
Some numbers
\caption{Title of table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```