# cross-referencing figures : Any way to use Fig. instead of figure

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, ieeetran

I'm using `IEEEtran.cls` to produce an article. When setting captions on figures, the text begins with

> Fig 1.

(for example).

However, when I reference this figure by using `\ref{img:something}`, this is rendered to

> figure 1

Is there a way to tweak the `\ref` command so that it be consistent with captions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you're planning on submitting an article to IEEE, just comply with their template and focus on the content of your paper. Don't try to change the default style set up by the `IEEEtrans`, or you run the risk of seeing your article rejected/delayed.

Comment: HI, This was a remark done by one of hte reviewers. They want me to change this.

Comment: Please see these, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135482/how-to-change-figure-caption-to-fig-1-in-stead-of-fig-1

Comment: Are you using the `hyperref` package and, by some chance, have you made `\ref` into an alias for `\autoref`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be loading a separate package; IEEEtran does not attempt to format the number from `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

See Fig.\,\ref{fig:a}

\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{a figure}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I use the `refstyle` package to format references; for your purposes you'd use something like:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{refstyle}
    \def\RSfigtxt{Fig.\,}%
    \def\RSfigstxt{Figs~}%
    \def\RSFigtxt{Fig.\,}%
    \def\RSFigstxt{Figs~}%
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

See \figref{fig:a}

\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{a figure}
\caption{A figure}
\figlabel{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

See the file `refstyle.cfg` for a full listing of commands that can be modified.