# Change figure caption name only in one figure, not all

Tags: floats, captions

I saw here [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures) , by

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
```

but if you do that, it changes all of the figures captions. How to change only some of them?

but I have 3 figures, I want default caption for figure 1 and 3, but Photo caption for figure 2.

so it should be like, Figure 1, Photo 1, Figure 2.

```
\begin{figure} 
      ...
      \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure} 
       ....
       \caption{This is a photo.}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
       ...
       \caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: After reading your comment to Herbert's answer, I've undeleted mine. You can keep his answer accepted, I don't mind :-), but since you mentioned my answer was the one you were going to use, I think it was worth to undelete it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

do it inside the environment, then it is local:

```
\begin{figure} 
   \renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
       ....
       \caption{This is a photo.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It looks like he wants a different environment. In his example he wants the output to be Figure 1, Photo 1, Figure 2. In this way, you'll get Figure 1, Photo 2, Figure 3.

Comment: Ok so by adding  \setcounter{figure}{0} in to the second figure together with this, it works. Well I was going to accept the other answer, but since it is deleted I am gonna choose this one. so

Answer (score 11):

The numbering showed in your question suggest that you want independent counters for photos and pictures, so it seems that you want a new independent floating object.

Using the [`newfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package you can easily define this new type of float object for your photos:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lop]{photo}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}


\begin{photo} 
\centering
B
\caption{This is a photo.}
\end{photo}


\begin{figure}
\centering
C
\caption{This is a figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to change only caption as I have a style file which may be styling figure environments, and I don't want photo differ from figure in that sense

Comment: @EmmetB I see. Then this answer is not useful, so I'll delete it.

Comment: @EmmetB Answer has been undeleted by [request](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13353884#13353884).