# Change autoref and caption name for only one figure

Tags: floats, captions, examples, autoref

I saw in [Change figure caption name only in one figure, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155584/change-figure-caption-name-only-in-one-figure-not-all) how to change the caption name for only one figure but I need to change de autoref name too.

Using

```
\begin{figure} 
   \renewcommand\figurename{Example}
      ....
      \caption{This is an example.}
\end{figure}
```

The figure caption change for "Example" but in te autoref it said "Figure".

How can I override figurename and autorefname for only one figure?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should the counter associated with the "Example" float be the same as the counter associated with "figure" floats? I.e., should the numbering go like Figure 5, Figure 6, Example 7, Figure 8, Figure 9, etc? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\autoref` uses the counter name in the anchor name to get the term for the reference.

There are various workarounds.

The figure:

```
\begin{figure}
  \renewcommand*{\figurename}{Example}
  ...
  \caption{This is an example.}
  \label{exp}
\end{figure}
```

Workarounds:

- `\ref` instead of `\autoref`:

  ```
  Example~\ref{exp}
  ```
- `\ref` instead of `\autoref` with including "Example" in the link:

  ```
  \hyperref[exp]{Example~\ref*{exp}}
  ```
- Redefining `\p@figure` to include "Example" as prefix to the reference:

  ```
  \begin{figure}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\p@figure}{Example~}
    \makeatother
    ... % see above
  \end{figure}

  \ref{exp}% -> Example <number>
  ```
- New counter `example`:

  ```
  % preamble
  \newcounter{example}
  \def\exampleautorefname{Example}

  \begin{figure}
    \setcounter{example}{\value{figure}}
    \refstepcounter{example}
    \label{exp}
    ...
    \caption{This is an example.}
  \end{figure}

  \autoref{exp}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose that you use the facilities of the `cleveref` package to achieve your typesetting objective. You should

- load the `cleveref` package with the options `nameinlink`, `noabbrev`, and `capitalize`; this will make the output of `\cref` look like that of `autoref`. (Note: `cleveref` must be loaded after `hyperref`.)
- provide the optional argument `example` to the `\label` instruction:

  ```
  \label[example]{fig:xyz}
  ```

Of course, keep issuing the instruction `\renewcommand\figurename{Example}` *inside* the `figure` environment, as per the earlier solution.

No other changes required.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{figure}{7} % just for this case
\begin{figure} 
\renewcommand\figurename{Example} % as per the earlier solution
\centering
ABC
\caption{This is an example.} 
\label[example]{fig:xyz}  % note the optional argument: "example"
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to \cref{fig:xyz}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider defining a new float type.

FYI, `\floatname` defines `\fname@example` which is used by `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}% for \newfloat
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfloat{example}{htbp}{lox}
\floatname{example}{Example}
\newcommand{\examplename}{Example}

\begin{document}
\begin{example} 
   \caption{This is an example.}\label{test}
\end{example}

\autoref{test}
\end{document}
```