# How to rename specific Figure caption name?

Tags: tag

How to rename a specific Figure. Let's say Figure 3.6 to Diagram 3.6 without affecting the other figures in the list. I know I can use something like \renewcommand but this will change all the figures. Please if you know how to change this let me know.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [Change figure caption name only in one figure, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155584/134144).

Comment: You could create a new float for diagrams (newfloat package), but it would use different numbers.