# Change algorithm name without global change

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I am wondering is it possible instead of Algorithm 1" it could be something else, like "Code 1" without modifying other algorithms in my latex file (or without globally changing things).

I see this question has been asked many times but all of the solutions are either using different algorithm package or globally modify algorithm properties.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{Rule evaluator for classical attribute grammar}\label{alg:ag-eval}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{\texttt{AG\_EVAL}}{$r, Val$}
        \If{$r \equiv v_0 \texttt{=} g( v_1, \dots, v_n)$}
            \State $Val(v_0) \gets g( Val(v_1), \dots, Val(v_n))$
        \EndIf
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Change figure caption name only in one figure, not all](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155584/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was using `{ }` or *group* to wrap the algorithm to prevent changing global settings and use `floatname` command to update the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

{ % opening curly braces
\floatname{algorithm}{Code}  % replacing "Algorithm" with "Code"
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \caption{Rule evaluator for classical attribute grammar}\label{alg:ag-eval}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{\texttt{AG\_EVAL}}{$r, Val$}
        \If{$r \equiv v_0 \texttt{=} g( v_1, \dots, v_n)$}
            \State $Val(v_0) \gets g( Val(v_1), \dots, Val(v_n))$
        \EndIf
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
} % closing curly braces

\end{document}
```

[Credit](https://stackapps.com/users/54601/samcarter)

[Reference](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=59151781#59151781)

Comment: Great :) // However, if you'd edit your answer and emphasize the two lines of code like {% << and }% << it would be evident on-the-fly. Thanks

Comment: This is referred to as *scoping*. The `{`...`}` defines a *group*, where changes within the group is only temporary unless explicitly states as being global.