# How do i have capital name of figure?

Tags: floats

my figures in latex must have caption like this:
FIGURE 1. figure name
which command gives me this capital figure name?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
```

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{figure name}
\end{figure}
```

I need to have FIGURE1.figure name instead of FIGURE 1: figure name
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As you use `caption`, add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{UC}{\MakeUppercase{#1} #2}
\captionsetup{labelformat=UC} % for all labels
% or, only for figures:
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=UC} %
```

This way, cross-references with a package like `cleveref`, won't be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

`\renewcommand\figurename{FIGURE}`

Please note when using babel this must be enclosed within `\addto\captionsxxx{...}` or used after `\begin{document}`.

If you use the `caption` package anyway, you could also use this as alternative:

`\usepackage[figurename=FIGURE]{caption}`.

See also: [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

Comment: As you use `caption, add

Comment: thank you very much. that was useful. and also i need a caption like this:FIGURE 2. figure name. But with \renewcommand\figurename{FIGURE}  i have  FIGURE 1:figure name. How can i fix this?

Comment: @Bernard When I answered this the questioner didn't mention the `caption` package. However, just added something to my answer.

Comment: Oh! I didn't one could set it this way. But does it set figurename in capital letters also outside caption?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. I must confess that I didn't thought about `\nameref` et. al. For that reason I upvoted your answer ;-)