# Changing figurename in paper document class?

Tags: captions

I am looking to change the figure name and table name for captions in the `paper` environment. In particular, I'd like to change both Fig. and Tab. to Figure and Table. The question [answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures) does not work in the for the paper document class.

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{hello}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{there}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

works succesfully. However,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{paper}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{hello}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{there}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

does not.

Comment: Try `\figureshortname`.

Comment: Done. I guess the class probably has documentation but there are some 'non-standard' names like this listed in the class and signalled with ` % <-- paper` so they are relatively easy to find should you need more. `\tableshortname` is probably the most likely.

Comment: Yes, `\tableshortname` works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class uses `\figureshortname` for the abbreviation `Fig.`, so you need to redefine this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{paper}
\renewcommand*\figurename{hello}
\renewcommand*\figureshortname{hi}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{there}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: short figure name]