# Combination of 'changing the caption of Figure' and 'List of anything'

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

In the paper I am writing, I need:

1. **part of** the captions 'Example 1' instead of 'Fig.1' as the caption of some pictures (Not all the figures, so `\usepackage[figurename=Example.]{caption}` is not suitbale). This requirement is similar to [Change the caption name of a specific figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316216/change-the-caption-name-of-a-specific-figure).
2. At the same time, I need both the List of Figures and List of Examples. I found the way to insert 'List of Anything' such as [List of Anything](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things).

But how could I be able to combine the two requirements: 1. Change few particular caption to Example; 2. Insert a List of Example after contents.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

--- For the comments from Peter ---

I cannot include the code in the comment as it is too long. Simply replace the "memoir" with "book" then you will see the problem. I have no idea why it is so difficult to understand what I mean (below code). BTW, thank you for your previous answer. Goodbye from a KYM (Kind Young Man).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlistof{listofexamples}{loe}{List of Examples}
\newfloat{example}{loe}{Example}

\begin{doument}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofexamples

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
 %\includegraphics... for a picture
\caption{A picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{example}
\centering
%\includegraphics... for an illustration
\caption{An illustration}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

For others meet the same problem, I find [float environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/new-figure-environment) and [list of anything](https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class (covers the `book`, `report` and `article` classes) lets you do this (set up a new List of... and new float environment).

First for the List of Examples:

```
\newlistof{listofexamples}{loe}{List of Examples}
```

which will create a command`\listofexamples` which when called in the document will produce a heading **List of Examples** followed by data from an `.loe` file (just like `\listoffigures` produces **List of Figures** followed by data from a `.lof` file).

Then for your examples create a new Example float (like the Figure float):

```
\newfloat{example}{loe}{Example}
```

after which

```
\begin{example}
% contents of the example
\caption{A caption for the example}
\end{example}
```

will act like a Figure but with its own caption style and numbering.

Here is a fuller example (but remove any typos):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlistof{listofexamples}{loe}{List of Examples}
\newfloat{example}{loe}{Example}

\begin{doument}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofexamples

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
 %\includegraphics... for a picture
\caption{A picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{example}
\centering
%\includegraphics... for an illustration
\caption{An illustration}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

For more detailed information see the documentation (`> texdoc memoir` sections 9.3 and 10.1)

On the other hand there might be a package that lets you do something similar.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am not sure if `\includegraphics` can be used in the defined 'example' environment since I want to insert 'figure format' example only with different caption 'Example.' instead of 'Fig.'. It would be better if you could an example code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Raymond Did you try an `\includegraphics` in the `example` environment? `\includegraphics` can be used anywhere, not just in a `figure` environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your example works, however, it seems these are based on the document class "memoir". Since the document I wrote is based on the book class, and it cause errors when I change the class from "book" to "memoir".

Comment: @Raymond I said that it worked in the `memoir` class. You did not say what class you were using. I have no idea why you are getting errors moving from the `book` to `memoir` class as you have not bothered to show any code. Goodbye from a GOM (Grumpy Old Man).