# Renaming the label of figure just in some cases

Tags: tables, captions

I would like to change the caption of Figure for Table, just on a particular case, which is when such a figure is a table. The last thing is about the position of the caption and its numbering. I want to put it on the top centered, saying something like "Table 2. XXX". I don't really need to worry about having later a list of tables or figures, just to let you know.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures) is the same question answered.

Comment: But the link provides a way to change the caption for all figures, and I don't want it. I want to change it, in some parts of the article.

Comment: Well, you can revert back to "Figure" with the same method. Why don't you just call your image a table though? You can put graphics inside a table environment. `\begin{table}
  \caption{This is my table}
  \includegraphics{pictureoftable}
\end{table}`

Comment: What do you want to change the labelling to? `Figure 2: Figure caption` to `MyFigure 2: Figure caption`?

Comment: A `table` environment can contain *anything*, for instance `\includegraphics`. There's no law imposing that `\includegraphics` has to be inside a `figure` environment.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide an MWE in the future for the quickest help. The (at least) two ways of doing what you want, sort of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% what you are asking to do (rename "Figure" in caption to "Table"):
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Table}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{This is my table}
  <picture of table>
\end{figure}
% The problem with this though, is that the number (e.g. "Table #: ...") will be
% counted as a figure still, so you really shouldn't do it this way.

% anyhow, to revert back to the usual "Figure" nomenclature:
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

% But, actually, you should just call it a table:
\begin{table}
  \caption{This is my table}
  <picture of table>
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the problem with the incorrect "table" number you'd get (well, it's technically *correct* because the number would be the count of figure environments, which you'd still be doing even if you rename the caption).

You should just place your image inside a table environment, as I show at the bottom of the example.

Comment: You could spare one `\renewcommand{\figurename}{\tablename}` by using it before `\caption` in the `figure` environment -- it won't leak outside then! As you noticed already: The counter is still the wrong one!

Answer (score 2):

Using a `table` environment is easier, actually -- if the screenshot is made with high quality, nobody will notice that the 'table' is a figure actually, especially in printing!

If somebody insists on a `figure` environment, one has to change the `\@captype` from `figure` to `table` inside of the figure environment with `\def` or `\renewcommand`. This way, the change is restricted to the group formed by the environment and does not leak outside.

`\caption` uses the same name for the counter as `\@captype` and looks for something like `\csname \@captype name\endcsname` to enter the name!

The only thing to worry still about this: You have to use a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\clearpage
\section{A section with a 'figure'}

\makeatletter
\begin{figure}
  \renewcommand{\@captype}{table}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ente}
  \caption{A nice 'table'}
\end{figure}
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

[image]