# Change "Figure" by another word in caption text

Tags: captions

I'm preparing a beamer presentation and I have this part of code

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{img1.png}
            \caption[Figura 1]{O Círculo Osculador de $\alpha$ em $s$.}
        \end{figure}
    \end{center}
```

that generates this [image]

I would like to know how to change the word "Figure" in "Figure 1" by another word because I would like to put the translation of "Figure" to my language in the beamer presentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}` ? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

Comment: Use `\usepackage[???]{babel}` to load some language. Replace `???` by the language, for example, `portuguese`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `center`, just use `\begin{figure}\centering`.

Comment: @DamienDtx, I tried now, but it doesn't works

Comment: @Sigur, yes, I'm using the \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

Comment: @George, it should work. See below. Maybe you have to install the language (or try with `brazil` instead).

Comment: Since your figure has number, I guess you are using some command to change `\figurename` behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel` is the right package to translate variables to some language.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}%
    \centering%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{text}
    \label{fig.A}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I realized that the babel package was in English language, I just change to Portuguese language and works without put the label command and the renewcommand suggested by DamienDtx.

Comment: `\label{fig.a}` has nothing to do with language, it is just to refer to the image with `\ref{fig.a}`, which of course have no sense if figure has no number.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do that so I don't have to use packages

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Εικόνα}
```