# Is there a way to configure captions in the `figure environment`?

Tags: floats, captions

Is there a way to tweak the `figure environment` so that it will prefix captions with some text other than `Figure` followed by auto-numbering? For argument's sake have (1) two types of caption prefixes, `Diagram` and `Problem`, (2) each with their own auto-numbering. So there are two questions.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 8 Feb 2019
%=======================
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \notationon 
    \chessboard[showmover=false,setfen={rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 1}] 
    \notationoff
    \caption{Starting Position}
    \label{}    
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \notationon 
    \chessboard[showmover=false,setfen={4k3/8/4b3/r7/7p/8/8/2K1Q2n b - - 0 1}]  
    \notationoff
    \caption{}
    \label{}    
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \notationon 
    \chessboard[showmover=false,setfen={2K4Q/5R2/8/3b1N2/5kN1/8/P7/b7 b - - 0 1}]   
    \notationoff
    \caption{}
    \label{}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you dont mind, could you re-post it as two questions instead? Just for future usage :)

Comment: Might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures

Comment: you need to define a new float/captiontype. E.g. with the newfloat package.

Comment: And I don't think that your \notationon/\notationoff commands are doing anything sensible together with chessboard.

Comment: The package `caption` has `\captionsetup` with a lot of options...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmmm … In the context of `\fenboard` I could have sworn they turn the `file` and `rank` labels on/off. But you are right, here they serve no purpose. So, out they will go.

Comment: `\fenboard`, `\notationon`, `\showboard`  are commands from skak (loaded by xskak). `\chessboard` is from the chessboard package. It has its own options to configure labels.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Got that. I did wonder though that I was using the `\chessboard` command without having to load the `chessboard` package. I suppose it too is loaded with `xskak`.

Comment: How about specifying new float types, one for Diagrams and another for Problems? The `memoir` class provides means of doing this, also for corresponding new "List of ...".

Comment: @Peter Wilson To my surprise I found that I can show my chessboards in the `table` environment just like they are shown in the `figure` environment, so this solved my problem for two floats. I'll the `memoir` class in mind though.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcounter{example1}
\setcounter{example1}{1}

\newcounter{example2}
\setcounter{example2}{1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\diagram[4]{%
   \protect\includegraphics[height=#2 in, keepaspectratio]{#3}\vskip \flushleft{Diagram \@nameuse{the#1}: #4.\vskip\stepcounter{example1}}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Problem[4]{%
    \protect\includegraphics[height=#2 in, keepaspectratio]{#3}\vskip \flushleft{Problem \@nameuse{the#1}: #4.\vskip\stepcounter{example2}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent \diagram{example1}{2}{example-image-a}{A caption}
\diagram{example1}{2}{example-image-b}{A caption}
\Problem{example2}{2}{example-image-c}{A caption}
\Problem{example2}{2}{example-image-duck}{Duck never gives a problem}
\end{document}
```

which would give you:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code does not compile for me.

Comment: @Reinhard Neuwirth do u have a `.log`? Nevertheless, I would indeed accept that these `macros` are fragile.

Comment: It looks like the key to answering my problem is the `caption` package and its `\captionsetup` command` as suggested by @Christian Hupfer. Configuring caption names was the easy part, I am experimenting at the moment to associate individual numbering with different names.

Comment: @Reinhard Neuwirth if it's only one environment then it's fairly straightforward. Else it is a little bit tricky. I agree with you on your comment, nevertheless. This is just a lazy alternative. One thing to do (for me) is to put-in the `\tag`.