# Change the symbol after #number in figure/table caption

Tags: tables, floats, captions

This is slightly similar to the question about renaming the figure caption ([answered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)), but now I want to change the symbol appearing *right after* the number, e.g.:

`Figure 1: ...` into `Figure 1. ...`.

`Table 1: ...` into `Table 1. ...`.

- I use the `caption` package, but no `babel` (although all approaches
  are welcome).

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing a full example document, but the most obvious way would be with the labelsep option to the caption package: `\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}`, since you're using that. See the [documentation](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf). If that doesn't work for you, please post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Maybe add an answer to mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can set the punctuation that appears after the figure or table number using the caption package's `labelsep` option. E.g., to get a period:

```
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
```

See the [caption package documentation](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf), page 6.