# Double index in the same documents

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, numbering

I have a question about a problem that I am facing. I have a document composed by two different and independent parts in two where the second parts refers to just some elements of the first one. Both the parts shares a common information as for example bibliography.

What I would like to generate is a document where the numbering of each parts start from 1 (also Figures, Table etc. follow the same numbering...). For example:

> **Part I**
>
> *Chapter 1*    Section 1.x
>         Sub Section 1.x.y
>
> *Chapter 2*    Section 2.x
>         Sub Section 2.x.y  -->Fig. 2.x.1
>
> etc.
>
> **Part II**
>
> *Chapter 1*    Section 1.x
>         Sub Section 1.x.y
>
> *Chapter 2*    Section 2.x
>         Sub Section 2.x.y  -->Fig. 2.x.1
>
> etc.

As I said, the second part refers somehow to elements in the first one. Therefore, inside the Part II -Chapter 2 -Section 2.x, I can have for example, a reference to Section 2.x of Part I (lets say Fig. 2.x.1)

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Did you check http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17127 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2445 ? Do the solutions provided there solve your problem? If so, this is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Compared to the class `book`, chapters are reset at the begin of a new part and figures and tables are reset at the start of a new section. There are several methods to do that, see the links in the comment of Count Zero above.

It remains the problem, that the numbering is not unique and it is not clear, to which part figure 2.1.1 belong to, for example. The following example adds the part, if the reference points outside the current part:

> [image: References]

Each reference is prefixed by `\p@<counter>` that is redefined to expand to `\RefPart` with the current part number. `\RefPart` is defined using `\DeclareRobustCommand`, because it must not be expanded, when the label is written to the `.aux` file. This way the `\RefPart` is executed at time of `\ref` that can be called in both parts generating different references (with and without part prefix).

Additionally the example is tested with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
% numbering of chapters inside part:
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \renewcommand*{\theHchapter}{%
    \theHpart.\arabic{chapter}%
  }%
}{}
% numbering of figure/table inside section:
\@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\renewcommand*{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RefPart}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\x{#1}%
    \protected@edef\y{\thepart}%
    \ifx\x\y
    \else
      \x.%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\renewcommand*{\p@table}{\RefPart{\thepart}}
\renewcommand*{\p@figure}{\RefPart{\thepart}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{Chapter A}
Reference inside part: \ref{figE}\\
reference to other part: \ref{figEE}
\chapter{Chapter B}
\section{Section C}
\subsection{Subsection D}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure E}
\label{figE}
\end{figure}

\part{Second part}
\chapter{Chapter AA}
Reference to other part: \ref{figE}\\
reference inside part: \ref{figEE}   
\chapter{Chapter BB}
\section{Section CC}
\subsection{Subsection DD}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure EE}
\label{figEE}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```