# Global footnote counter in Koma-script book class

Tags: numbering, footnotes, koma-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous footnote numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering)

How can I achieve that footnotes have a global numbering scheme, and not a per chapter numbering?
I am using the `book class` from the `koma-script`. I am also using the `footmisc` package.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume

Comment: I did look there and did not find it.

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\makeatletter
  \@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Code-only answers are typically discouraged; like providing a cake without icing.