# Referencing footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I am in the position of needing footnotes for my document. I found that the syntax is:

```
Something pretty complicated\footnote{This complicated thing needs details.}
```

This will make my source hard to read so I have to ask you guys: is there any method to work like this?

```
Something pretty compLicated\footnote{ref:1}

\footnote{1}{This complicated thing needs details.}
```

Comment: Do these help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plain TeX then you can try this:

```
\input opmac

\let\fnoteori=\fnote
\def\fnote#1{\fnoteori{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname fn:#1\endcsname\relax Footnote not declared yet.%
   \else \csname fn:#1\endcsname\fi}}

\def\fnotedef#1#2{\toks0={#2}\openref\immediate\wref\sdef{{fn:#1}{\the\toks0}}}


Something pretty complicated\fnote{ref:1}

% at the end of the document (or somewhere else):
\fnotedef{ref:1}{This complicated thing needs details.}

\bye
```

If you are using different TeX macro (for example LaTeX) then you can find only the inspiration here. The `\fnotedef` macro saves the information to the working file (`aux`, `ref` etc.) in the format:

```
\sdef{fn:ref:1}{text}
```

When the document is processed again, then this file is read and `\sdef` macro defines `\fn:ref:1` as `text`. So, the `\fnote` macro can execute the original `\fnote` where the `\fn:ref:1` is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, that uses the `.aux` file for saving the footnotes. I don't think it's a real advancement in readability.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\victor@fnread}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{victor@#1@footnote}{#2}%
  \g@addto@macro\victor@footnotes{#2}%
}
\def\victor@footnotes{}%
\let\FOOTNOTE\victor@fnread
\AtEndDocument{%
  \gdef\victor@footnotesend{}%
  \let\FOOTNOTE\victor@fncheck
}
\newcommand{\victor@fncheck}[2]{%
  \g@addto@macro\victor@footnotesend{#2}%
}
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \ifx\victor@footnotes\victor@footnotesend\else
    \@latex@warning@no@line{Footnotes have changed, rerun LaTeX}%
  \fi
}

\let\victor@footnote@ori\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
  \victor@footnote@ori{\@nameuse{victor@#1@footnote}}%
}

\newcommand{\savefootnote}[2]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\FOOTNOTE{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\textheight=4cm % just for the example

\begin{document}

Something pretty complicated\footnote{ref:1}

\savefootnote{ref:1}{This complicated thing needs details.}

Whatever\footnote{ref:what} and another\footnote{ouch}

\savefootnote{ref:what}{OK}
\savefootnote{ouch}{Ouch}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A check for duplicate keys can be added. For the moment, just a warning the footnotes have changed is issued, if it's the case.