# Change label in align environment

Tags: align, counters, labels

In LaTeX, I'm using the documentclass `report` with different chapters. Now, when using the `align` environment for listing formulas with labels, i get labels like (2.1), (2.2), ..., the first number referring to the chapter, the second numbering the equation. How can I change this so it will number the equations with a single number throughout the entire document, i.e. so I get labels like (1), (2), ...? (Don't worry, I'm not using the equation numbering a whole lot. ;-) )

Btw, I would like to avoid the `\tag{}` command, as I want to keep latex to take care of the correct numbering. Any suggestions?

Cheers and many thanks in advance!
Jonas

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is very similar to [Continuous footnote numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10448), only you want `equation` instead of `footnote` in `\counterwithout`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for the quick reply, @TorbjørnT. ,  and sorry I didn't find that myself. Cheers, Jonas

Comment: No worries, it isn't always easy to find.