# continous footnote numbering does not work

Tags: footnotes

I read this answer and I still have footnotes that reset by each new page [Continuous footnote numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/continuous-footnote-numbering)

My preambel looks like this:

```
 %% Footnotes 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{page}
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip} 
\setlength{\dimen\footins}{10\baselineskip}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
```

Maybe this helps too:

```
\usepackage[
 automark,         
 nouppercase,
]{scrpage2}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\IfElseChapterDefined{
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
}{
\pagestyle{scrplain}
}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\IfElseChapterDefined{
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
}{
\automark[subsection]{section}
}
\IfElseChapterDefined{
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
}{
}
\IfChapterDefined{
\setheadsepline{0.6pt}[\color{rgb:black,100}]
%\setfootsepline{0.6pt}[\color{rgb:black,100}]
}
```

Please help.I am new to Latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragment into a complete compilable document with just the fragment and enough other code to show the problem.  But looking at your first bit of code, you should have `\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}` not `{page}` I think, as in the question you linked to.

Comment: chapter did not work either.

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal working example, like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to do this, and I wanted to share it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Make custom counter for the footnotes
% Patch the footnote command to bend to our needs
\patchcmd{\footnote}{\@mpfn}{{myfootnote}}\relax\relax
\patchcmd{\footnote}{\thempfn}{{\themyfootnote}}\relax\relax
% Test it out
\begin{document}
  Footnote one here\footnote{Footnote 1}
  \clearpage
  Footnote two here\footnote{Footnote 2}
\end{document}
```

### Note this though:

It's probably something else that is wrong, since this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\counterwithout{footnote}{page}
% Test it out
\begin{document}
  Footnote one here\footnote{Footnote 1}
  \clearpage
  Footnote two here\footnote{Footnote 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your second MWE I don't think that you need the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: The article class doesn’t reset footnote numbers by page,

Comment: @egreg Oh. I just assumed it did, heh :p