# Number footnotes continuously

Tags: numbering, footnotes

Bonjour à tou.tes !

In my document (compiled with LuaLaTeX) the footnote counter restarts at 1 in each new chapter.  How do I do to number all footnotes continuously?

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Bonjour, 
I'm trying\footnote{to use footnotes} hard !
\chapter{Chapter one}
Here I am\footnote{out there} so lost with it !
This is not a footnote\footnote{yolo}.
\chapter{Chapter 2}
encore une\footnote{cirhose}
\end{document}
```

After compilation:

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: That is the default behaviour for a document with chapters!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10448/35864: `\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}` should help you (if you are using an older version of LaTeX you may have to load the `chngcntr` package).

Comment: OK, it works ! 
Thanks for your incrediblely fast answer.

Comment: Very good. Can we close your question as a duplicate of the linked question? I should probably also say: Welcome to TeX.SX!