# Is it possible to have the numbering of citations to continue after a new chapter?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am writing my thesis and would like to have the numbering of the citations using autocite not to be reseted to 1 everytime a new chapter starts. I would like to have a continous numbering of my citations in the footer. I am new to latex so im grateful for any help :)

```
\documentclass[ngerman, 11pt, a4paper, dottedtoc,
               headinclude, twoside=true, footinclude=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=verbose,
            bibstyle=alphabetic, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{XXX.bib}
```

Comment: AFAICS the only numbering you get are the footnote numbers. Those may be rest every chapter, but that can be changed with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10448/35864.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly!